# Tkinter TreeVIew Horizontal Scrollbar not working

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I am building a normal table using tkinter and treeview. The horizontal scrollbar is visible but not activated although I have configured the settings. Wondering what is wrong with the code?
[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter.ttk import LabelFrame
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkcalendar import Calendar
from tkinter import messagebox
import webbrowser
import datetime
from io import BytesIO
from tkinter import filedialog


login_window = tk.Tk()
login_window.geometry('950x600')

Table_frame = tk.Frame(login_window, bd=15, relief='ridge', width=900, height=200)
Table_frame.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='nsew')

destination_table = ttk.Treeview(Table_frame)
destination_table.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

scroll_x = ttk.Scrollbar(Table_frame, orient='horizontal')
scroll_x.configure(command=destination_table.xview)
scroll_x.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)

destination_table.configure(xscrollcommand = scroll_x.set)

destination_table["columns"]=("destinationname", "rate", "description", "estimatedprice","address", "contact", "operationtime", "type", "tags")

destination_table["show"] = "headings"

destination_table.heading("destinationname", text="Destination Name")
destination_table.heading("rate", text="Ratings")
destination_table.heading("description", text="Description")
destination_table.heading("estimatedprice", text="Estimated Price")
destination_table.heading("address", text="Address")
destination_table.heading("contact", text="Contact")
destination_table.heading("operationtime", text="Operation Time")
destination_table.heading("type", text="Destination type")
destination_table.heading("tags", text="Tags")


destination_table.column("destinationname", width=100)

login_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter

Comment: @newbies. Your code is working. You had this `geometry('950x600')`. You must resize windows. And then column' Tags' to resize to right then you will see a horizontal bar moving to left.

Answer (score 0):

The treeview `destination_table` will be resized to show all the columns by default, so the horizontal scrollbar is not activated.

You can make the parent frame `Table_frame` to be resized to fit the width of its parent window, then the treeview inside it will also be resized to fit its width.  Then the horizontal scrollbar will be activated since the width is not wide enough to show all the columns.

As *grid* layout manager is used on the frame `Table_frame`, just adding the following line will make the frame to fit the window width:

```py
login_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Result:

[image]